# How to run my script, After Wordpress Elementor scripts fully loaded?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, elementor

I am a newbie to **Wordpress**, But i have good experience in 
**java** development. I have developed a small **Wordpress** site using **OceanWP**, **Elementor**. In the Home page, I need to show the number of registered members in my site.

So, while developing the page, I used **`COUNTER WIDGET`** of the **Elementor** ,with **`STARTING NUMBER`** is **`1`** and **`ENDING NUMBER`** is **`5`** . But actually I need to call the **DB** to fetch the number of registered members using **ajax** and display it in home page. So I decided to write own custom code using **jQuery** to do ajax call after my DOM is fully loaded.

I have written below code in my **functions.php**

```
function load_js_assets() {

    if( is_page( 26 ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'home-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/ucws-js/home-js.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
    } 
}

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_assets' );
```

Then my **home-js.js** will be as below,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    alert("Default members : "+$("#registered-Members").text()); //alerts --> Default members : 1 // But expected Default members : 5
    getRegisteredMembers_UsingAjaxCall(); //ajax call to DB to get total number of registered members dynamically
});
```

**My Expectation :** I need to call or load my `jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){}` , after **Elemetor** loads all its **`js`** files. Kindly guide me,If i am going in the wrong way.

**Note :** I welcome all the suggestions to achieve my requirement.

Comment: can you see the ajax code in the source when loading the page?

Comment: Ajax are all working fine....

Comment: so AJAX shows in the source code, but it's not fetching the number of registered members?

Comment: Ajax and getting data will not be a problem... I receive data from the dB and I can see the value in alert box. But I cannot display because of elementor COUNTER WIDGET ... Because i think elementor counter run some scripts to display animation , after my script loaded...so I need to prioritize it.

Answer (score 0):

Try these hooks in your functions.php theme
https://code.elementor.com/js-hooks/

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {
    if ( ! defined( 'ELEMENTOR_VERSION' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery( function( $ ) {
            // jquery example
            console.log($('body'));
        } );
    </script>
    <?php
} );
```